# Use Gradle to upload archives to GitLab Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, gradle, gitlab

I use Gradle and [Gradle Maven plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) to upload archives to Maven Central. This works fine. I want to upload the same archives also to the GitLab Maven repository. Upload to this repo requires [authentication with special HTTP header values](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/packages/maven_repository.html#authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token). But I don't know how to do that with the Gradle Maven plugin. The [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/packages/maven_repository.html) describes a Maven based build process using `pom.xml` and `settings.xml`. What I currently have is this:

Files created with Gradle:

```
build/libs
├── wms-1.2.0.jar
├── wms-1.2.0.jar.asc
├── wms-1.2.0-javadoc.jar
├── wms-1.2.0-javadoc.jar.asc
├── wms-1.2.0-sources.jar
└── wms-1.2.0-sources.jar.asc
build/poms
└── pom-default.xml
```

Files according to the GitLab documentation:

```
pom.xml
settings.xml
```

When I execute

```
mvn deploy -s settings.xml
```

then `pom-default.xml` must be "mixed into" `pom.xml` and `build/libs/*` must be used as archive location. How can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please note that [the `maven-publish` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/publishing_maven.html) “is now the preferred option for publishing [Maven] artifacts” with Gradle (see also the note at the top of [the page](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/maven_plugin.html) you linked). Doing what you need with the `maven` plugin would be more cumbersome as it’s both more intricate and not as well documented, IMHO. Hence, I hope you won’t mind when I answer your question with the `maven-publish` plugin in mind.

As for the authentication with special HTTP header values, you should be able to solve this as follows ([via](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/repository_types.html#using_http_header_authentication)):

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                name = "Private-Token"
                value = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"
            }
            authentication {
                header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I you really want to use the old `maven` plugin then I’d suggest to start researching from [this section](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sec:deploying_to_a_maven_repository) of the documentation on how to solve the authentication issue.

---

BTW: I have mainly answered your question on how to authenticate with GitLab here. If you should have trouble with configuring the publication, then I’d recommend to post this as a separate question with more details on your setup and on maybe what you’ve tried already.

---

Edited to add: if you need to use different header credentials depending on certain command line options, you could change the `credentials` configuration above to something like the following:

```
credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
    if (project.hasProperty('jobToken')) {
      name = "Job-Token"
      value = project.property('jobToken')
    } else {
      name = "Private-Token"
      value = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    }
}
```

In this example, you could run `./gradlew -PjobToken=REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_JOB_TOKEN …` in GitLab CI jobs while leaving out the `-PjobToken=…` part when working locally.

Comment: I migrated my `build.gradle` to use `maven-publish` plugin and thanks to @Chriki my artifacts are now uploaded to gitlab.com.  The only open question is: How can I define two header values? I have to use `Private-Token` when I use Gradle at the commandline, but `Job-Token` with GitLab CI jobs. I want to define both headers with `HttpHeaderCredentials`.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to show how using different header credentials in different environments could work.

Comment: I just want to note that `HttpHeaderCredentials` requires at least Gradle 4.10.

Comment: The bit about how to set up different credentials in different environments is just what I needed! Thanks, @Chriki! I just changed it to check for the presence of the GitLab job token environment variable, rather than a command-line argument -- but same principle!